# Is the probabilitistic distribution of the digits in the Chaitin's constant computable?

Tags: computability, incompleteness

The Chaitin constant can in principle be computed with exponential effort on each sucessive digit by brute forcing all programs of a given length and simply proving special theorems on each case that say if the particular program will halt or not

Can we say *anything* about the probability distribution of the digits themselves? are they randomly distributed in some rigorous sense?

Comment: Every Martin-Löf random is [absolutely normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).

Comment: No, if it was "simply proving theorem", it would be computable. It is not, because proving theorem is not simple, and can be even impossible. So, "in principle", the Chaitin constant can not be computed.

Comment: that would be true if there were Turing machines for which their halting was undecidable. But, for As far as I can tell, no theorem asserts that, it is only asserted that there is no general algorithm to evaluate halting **for any machine**

Comment: @lurscher I'm sorry but you're wrong. The fact that there is no general algorithm implies that for some machine, you can't prove if it halts or not. It's the basics of computability that I teach in my university.